# Parse the XML data using library(xml2) [in R]

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to solve Data Cleaning course in Coursera. I am encountering troubles in coding:

1. How to parse the XML data (using library: xml2) and use it to find the number of restaurants?
2. How to parse XML to data frame?

Read the XML data on Baltimore restaurants from here:
https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Frestaurants.xml

**How many restaurants have zipcode 21231?**

```
library(xml2)
x <- read_xml("https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Frestaurants.xml")
y <- as.numeric(xml_path(xml_find_all(x, "//row[@zipcode='21231']]")))
y
```

or

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
pg <- read_html ("https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Frestaurants.xml")
    html_nodes(pg, "//row[@zipcode='21231']]") %>% 
            map(xml_attrs) %>% 
            map_df(~as.list(.))
```

I tried to code two ways but none worked. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking for something like this?

```
length( xml_find_all( x, './/zipcode[text()="21231"]' ) )
[1] 127
```